# Accessing child collection in query

Tags: c#, linq

I am populating a list using

```
List<Country> countries = new List<Country> 
{ 
   new Country() 
   {
      CountryID = "US",
      City = new List<City>
      {
         new City()
         {
            CountryID = "US", CityName = "dfdsf", sqkm = 2803
         }
      }
   }
};
```

and so on

How to access **sqkm** in the following query?

```
var countryQuery = countries
    .Select(c => new { Id = c.CountryId, Area = c.City.sqkm???});
```

`c.city.sqkm` gives compilation error...how to modify query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Julien, if you want one, use First(); if you want the entire list, you can do:

```
c.city.Select(i => i.sqkm) // returns array
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the first city of your list of cities, use `c.city.First().sqkm`

EDIT: in response to your comment, if you want every sqkm defined in every country then use:

```
countries.SelectMany(c => c.city)
```

If you want all cities per country, you already have that with only `c.city` since it's already a list (which should be renamed Countries to be clearer).

EDIT2: `countries.SelectMany(c => c.City).Where(city => city.sqkm > 2000);`

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify which list item you want either by using an index as below, or by using an extension method that returns a single record.

```
var countryQuery = countries
.Select(c => new { Id = c.CountryId, Area = c.city[0].sqkm})
```

Answer (score 1):

The city is a list, so you should define the city you want.

To get the first:

```
var countryQuery = countries
    .Select(c => new { Id = c.CountryId, Area = c.city.First().sqkm});
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want all sqkm from all cities in all contries [SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) is your friend.

```
countries.SelectMany(country => country.Cities).Select(city => city.sqkm);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var countryQuery = countries
    .Select(c => c.City.Foreach(city => new { Id = c.CountryId, Area = city.sqkm } ));
```